# Post reply on SharePoint online discussion board using REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am trying to post reply on a particular discussion of SharePoint online discussion board through REST API but unable to do it. I don't want to use SP.utilities as this REST API will be called from Android App.

Below is the code which I am implementing:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"../_api/web/Lists/getbytitle(listname)/items?$filter=ParentItemID eq 40",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "IF-MATCH": "*"

    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Successfully posted!!");
    },
    error: function (error) {
    alert("error");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Instead of creating reply inside discussion, it is creating a new discussion item.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you get solution??

Comment: can help in this.http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190174/how-to-get-all-replies-for-particular-question-of-discussion-board-using-sharepo/190180?noredirect=1#comment200544_190180

Comment: @Android Developer : Haven't got any solution yet. I am badly stuck with this. :-(

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper : the Link which u shared is for fetching the replies, but I needed something to Post reply using REST. :(

Comment: but i am stuck in getting replies so i was share link of my question help me

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper :  For fetching replies, below is the REST URL that can be used.

    sitUrl/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=Title,Author/ID,Author/Title,Author/SipAddress,Body,Modified&$expand=Author/ID,Author/Title,Author/SipAddress&$filter=ParentItemID eq 'ID'   ;

Here ,Pass 'ID' value as value of Id for your question/discussion.

Comment: i am trying to fetch all replies which is in particular Question folder so  i have that folder path. so now i can get it but i am facing problem is some items didnt have parent id because that i have manually add in that replies folder

Comment: actually i have some other filed column in discussion board as well same in replies. now when i give reply from subject view  to particular question its create parent ID for it and just give write to body column not other fields. but it want to fill all fileds. and if i am trying to see all replies in management view and create new item then it provide to feel all filed items but its not fill parent ID. so i am confuse how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

For creating a *message item* (reply) in Discussion Board the following properties needs to be specified:

- `FileSystemObjectType` for a message items needs to be set to 0
- `ContentTypeId`- content type Id of message item
- `ParentItemID` - discussion item (container for messages) id

**Regarding `ParentItemID` property**

`ParentItemID` property could not be specified via message payload since it is a read only property, it means the following query for creating a message item fails:

```
Url  /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Discussions')/items
Method POST
Data { 
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.DiscussionsListItem" },
   'Body': "Message text goes here",  
   'FileSystemObjectType': 0, 
   'ContentTypeId': '<MessageContentTypeId>', 
   'ParentItemID': <DiscussionItemId> 
}
```

**Solution**

The following example demonstrates how to to create a message (reply) in Discussion Board via SharePoint REST API.

> For creating a message under a discussion item (folder) the following
>   approach is used: once message item is created, it's getting moved
>   under a discussion item

```
var listTitle = "Discussions"; //Discussions Board title
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var messagePayload = {
   '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.DiscussionsListItem" },  //set DiscussionBoard entity type name
   'Body': "Message text goes here",  //message Body
   'FileSystemObjectType': 0, //set to 0 to make sure Message Item is created
   'ContentTypeId': '0x0107008822E9328717EB48B3B665EE2266388E', //set Message content type
   'ParentItemID': 123   //set Discussion item (topic) Id
};

createNewDiscussionReply(webUrl,listTitle,messagePayload)
.done(function(item)
{
    console.log('Message(reply) has been sent');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function executeJson(options) 
{
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    var method = options.method || "GET";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: options.url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if("data" in options) {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}


function createListItem(webUrl,listTitle,payload){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
        "method": 'POST',
        "data": payload
    });
}

function moveListItem(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,folderUrl){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getItemById(" + itemId + ")?$select=FileDirRef,FileRef";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url
    })  
    .then(function(result){
        var fileUrl = result.d.FileRef;
        var fileDirRef = result.d.FileDirRef;
        var moveFileUrl = fileUrl.replace(fileDirRef,folderUrl);
        var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + fileUrl + "')/moveto(newurl='" + moveFileUrl + "',flags=1)";
        return executeJson({
            "url" :url,
            "method": 'POST'
        });
     });
}


function getParentTopic(webUrl,listTitle,itemId){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getItemById(" + itemId + ")/Folder";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
    });
}


function createNewDiscussionReply(webUrl,listTitle, messagePayload){ 
    var topicUrl = null;
    return getParentTopic(webUrl,listTitle,messagePayload.ParentItemID)
    .then(function(result){
        topicUrl = result.d.ServerRelativeUrl;
        return createListItem(webUrl,listTitle,messagePayload);
    })
    .then(function(result){
        var itemId = result.d.Id;
        return moveListItem(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,topicUrl);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why is it so?
Why sharepoint team didn't gave a simple endpoint to create a reply under a discussion ???

Comment: While this appears to work (the reply shows up in the discussion thread of the parent post) it does not set the `ParentItemID` property on the reply, it remains `null` which breaks some of the features of discussions. See this article: [REST api support for discussion list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/d4de96cc-53eb-4579-a7d4-97e575b08620/rest-api-support-for-new-discussion-list-in-community-site-of-sharepoint-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint)